# Unclosed `<del>` tag in edit history when removing del'ed text

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, revisions-list, design

I noticed yesterday that the edit history contains unclosed tags if a `<del>` tag is removed from it.  See revision 5 of [this question's edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1475/list) to see what I'm talking about. In revision 4 I put the text "say, 30 minutes?" inside a `<del></del>`.  Then in revision 5 I rolled back to revision 3 (i.e. removed the `<del></del>`).  However, in the edit history for revision 5, the `<del>` tag is never closed, making it look like the whole second paragraph was deleted as well.

---

I don't know if this is specific to the `<del>` tag or not.  I have at least confirmed (on [this question's edit history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1066/list)) that the problem isn't reproducible for the `<b>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has been fixed and is marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).